# silex, .htaccess, webhosting doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-hosting, silex

Here's my file .htaccess on local machine and web hosting, on local everything works well, but on web-hosting i can access web/index.php only like example.com/web/index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure htaccess files are enabled on your hosting server, and are you sure they're using apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *RewriteBase* is not correct, you should put only the directory, not the file name. Also if your root project is the web project, your rewrite base should be only / and in the rewrite rule you should tell apache were to redirect all of your requests. So, you should use something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /web/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But keep in mind that only your web folder must be publicly accessible, not your entire project. You should change that if you can (otherwise you should put an .htaccess file in the root project and another in the web folder, but this is beyond the scope of your question).

Comment: Thanks, so i should give all files except, web/index.php, user permissions to execute, not read/write, yeap? Thanks for answer, I'll check it today/tomorrow, btw I already asked support they answered me that everything should work and I have incorrect .htaccess

Comment: Yes, your .htacess file *was incorrect*, your RewriteBase was not right. As for the file permissions, you can use 2 .htaccess, one that denies everything in the root folder, and one similar to the sample I gave you in the *web* folder (then your RewriteBase should be ```RewriteBase /web```). You don't need to touch file permissions. But this is a little off your question :-)

Comment: thanks, .httaccess i took from silex, that's why i wonder why it doesn't work